# Is the design correct using WebFlux Framework?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Have written a microservice(Using webFlux) which in turn calls three other microservices(Not using webflux). New microservice call the other three using flatmap. and controller is returning Mono . Is this correct Design. Do I need to pushlishOn?

```
Mono<String> result  =service1.api(input)
.flatmap(innput-> service2.api).flatmap(input-> service3.api);
```

And Controller is also Returning Mono . Is the design correct. Will it be working in non-blocking way?

Comment: "Will it be working in non-blocking way?", that depends on how your `service1.api()`,  `service2.api()` and `service3.api()` methods work. Are those non-blocking or not? Feel free to share the code you used to write those.

Answer (score 1):

The `publishOn` method does not change code either into non-blocking or blocking code. All it does is force downstream operators to run in a different thread. However, if the service calls made within those threads are blocking, then you'll just be blocking another thread if you use `publishOn`.

So, to answer "Will it be working in non-blocking way", it actually depends on how you implemented `service1.api()`, `service2.api()` and `service3.api()`. If they synchronously fetch your data, then it will still be blocking, no matter what you do.

However, if you use the new [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) API for example to reactively fetch your data from your three microservices properly, then yes, it should be non-blocking.

Comment: Used the newer WebClient API to fetch the data from all the services. so it should work in non-blocking way.

Comment: Is there a way I can see the time taken by each microservice to complete its job